# How to make some if (or expressions) shorter with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have some c# lines like this:

```
if (justification.Contains("CT_") ||
justification.Contains("CTPD_") ||
justification.Contains("PACS_") ||
justification.Contains("NMG_") ||
justification.Contains("TFS_ID") ||
justification.Contains("AX_") ||
justification.Contains("MR_") ||
justification.Contains("FALSE_POSITIVE") ||                             
justification.Contains("EXPLICIT_ARCH_TEAM_DESIGN_DECISON") ||
justification.Contains("EXPLICIT_ARCH_TEAM_DESIGN_DECISION"))
{
    // justification is ok.
}else
{
    reporter.Report(syntaxNode.GetLocation(), syntaxNode,
    Resources.SpecifySuppressMessageJustificationTitle);
}
```

my idea was to put all these strings into an arra and at my IF Expression i just iterate my array (or enumerate an IEnumerable). But how can I Do this?

i started with this here:

```
IEnumerable<string> someValues = new List<string>() { "CT_", "CTPD","PACS_", "NMG_", "AX_" };

if (justification == BUT HOW I HAVE TO RUN THROUGH MY someValuesand get the
stringValues?)
{

}
```

Comment: What is the type of `justification`? Is it a `string`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do as below, if you need case insensitive contains check you can get upper case by using `justification.ToUpper()` since you already having value list in upper case

```
var someValues = new List<string>() { "CT_", "CTPD","PACS_", "NMG_", "AX_" };
if(someValues.Any(x=>justification.Contains(x))
{
   // justification is ok.
}else
{
   // not matching
}
```

Comment: 1st answer will be flagged as accepted! THANKS FOR THIS!
Tried also find a linq documentation example >>

Answer (score 5):

```
var someValues = new[] { "CT_", "CTPD","PACS_", "NMG_", "AX_" };

if (someValues.Any(x => justification.Contains(x))
{
    // justification is ok.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If justification is an [IEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx)(or a List), you can use [Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx)

Intercept produces a ***set*** of items that can be found in both lists.

```
IEnumerable<string> someValues = new List<string>() { "CTPD","PACS_",  "NMG_", "AX_"};

if (justification.Intersect(someValues).Any())
{
   // Atleast one match was found.
}
```

If the justification variable is a string, you can use [Any()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
if(someValues.Any(x => justification.Contains(x))
{
    // A match was found.
}
```

Comment: Ths won't work, since you're intersecting a string (which is an `IEnumerable<char>`) with an `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: If `justification` is a `string` then this answer is wrong. If `justification` is an `IEnumerable<string>` it would work.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan It is not stated anywhere that it is a string. So I assumed that it was a list. My answer has been edited to solve both cases.

Comment: I think that the original example calling `Contains` on something that looks like a prefix (MR_, etc), as well as the name of the variable, strongly imply it's a string.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan Yes, maybe, either way, two good answers were made on the string variation, and I gave my answer on the IEnumerable/List variation.